# Getting stackoverflow when cutting certain strings into slices

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

```
    @NotNull
public String text;
public int x;
public int y;
@NotNull
public ComponentText component;

public TextModule(@NotNull String text, int x, int y) {
    fr.setBidiFlag(true);
    fr.setUnicodeFlag(true);
    this.text = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    component = new ComponentText(x, y, ComponentText.TextAlignH.LEFT, ComponentText.TextAlignV.MIDDLE);
    component.getUnicode().setValue(true);

    if (this.x + fr.getStringWidth(text) > TextAdapter.wrapLength) {
        component.setPos(new Vec2d(0, 0));
        String[] strings = clipString(text);

        ComponentText string1 = new TextModule(strings[0], this.x, this.y).getComponent();
        component.add(string1);
        this.x = 0;
        this.y += fr.FONT_HEIGHT;

        TextModule string2 = new TextModule(strings[1], this.x, this.y);
        component.add(string2.getComponent());
        this.x = string2.x;
        this.y = string2.y;
    } else {
        component.getText().setValue(this.text);
        this.x += fr.getStringWidth(text);
    }
    fr.setBidiFlag(false);
    fr.setUnicodeFlag(false);
}

public String[] clipString(String string) {
    if (x + fr.getStringWidth(string) >= TextAdapter.wrapLength) {
        List<String> lines = fr.listFormattedStringToWidth(string, TextAdapter.wrapLength - x);
        if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
            String[] parts = new String[2];
            if (x + fr.getStringWidth(lines.get(0)) > TextAdapter.wrapLength) {
                parts[0] = "";
                parts[1] = string;
            }
            else {
                String line = lines.get(0);
                parts[0] = line;
                parts[1] = string.substring(parts[0].length());
            }
            return parts;
        }
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

I'm making a guide book that reads a text file from json. It's crashing with a stack overflow:

This is the text module, there are multiple modules such as a StackModule and a PlayerModule, all they do is set their own text to something special like colored or something.

Anyways, the highlight here is cutString. Basically, what I'm doing is getting the next string in line from the json like for example:

```
...
"learn how to manipulate light using reflection and refraction!",
"Ever wanted to suck items and entities with a single beam of light? Ever wanted to create a disco ball based quarry? How about creating a laser defense system? Or, heck, maybe you just wanted to make an epic laser show?",
...
```

What I'm doing with cutString is getting the next string in line, like for example the second line up above "Ever wanted to...", and cut it into 2 halves. One half will be the words in the beginning to fill up any trailing empty space from the previous string. The other half sets itself on a new line. This is all to wrap the strings nicely.

I'm getting a stackoverflow in cutString I THINK. The log is NOT specific enough but commenting out anything that uses cutString in textModule does away with the crash, but of course, removes all wrapping and trails out of the screen.

The log is:

```
[16:19:29] [Client thread/FATAL]: Unreported exception thrown!
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer.getFormatFromString(FontRenderer.java:945) ~[FontRenderer.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer.wrapFormattedStringToWidth(FontRenderer.java:848) ~[FontRenderer.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer.wrapFormattedStringToWidth(FontRenderer.java:849) ~[FontRenderer.class:?]
```

...

That method is:

```
    String wrapFormattedStringToWidth(String str, int wrapWidth)
{
    int i = this.sizeStringToWidth(str, wrapWidth);

    if (str.length() <= i)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        String s = str.substring(0, i);
        char c0 = str.charAt(i);
        boolean flag = c0 == 32 || c0 == 10;
        String s1 = getFormatFromString(s) + str.substring(i + (flag ? 1 : 0));
        return s + "\n" + this.wrapFormattedStringToWidth(s1, wrapWidth);
    }
}
```

The entire FontRenderer class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1cc0ae9b294ac7b27e4d64612d0da4bc

The TextModule class: https://github.com/TeamWizardry/TMT-Refraction/blob/master/src/main/java/com/teamwizardry/refraction/api/book/TextModule.java

The TextAdapter Class using the component object produced from TextModule: https://github.com/TeamWizardry/TMT-Refraction/blob/master/src/main/java/com/teamwizardry/refraction/api/book/TextAdapter.java

The class that's using the TextAdapter by reading json: https://github.com/TeamWizardry/TMT-Refraction/blob/master/src/main/java/com/teamwizardry/refraction/client/gui/GuiBook.java

And the json file: https://github.com/TeamWizardry/TMT-Refraction/blob/master/src/main/resources/assets/refraction/tablet/en_US.json

What could be causing this stack overflow? Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Quick reading, `wrapWidth` is never change. But this is clearly an infinite (or close too) recursive call. You should debug the `wrapFormattedStringToWidth` method to check if this is correct.

Comment: @AxelH Debugging cutString showed that it's splitting strings properly from what I can see. It eventually catches a string and loops it over and over again without splitting. But I only saw that happen once and can't reproduce it easily.

Comment: What should do `sizeStringToWidth` `getFormatFromString` and `wrapFormattedStringToWidth`. One of does is probably not doing is job, update your code with those information. Not sure the first code is usefull, there is no call of `wrapFormattedStringToWidth ` there.

Comment: @AxelH         List<String> lines = fr.listFormattedStringToWidth(string, TextAdapter.wrapLength - x);
That uses wrapFormattedStringToWidth directly. just converts to a list then runs it.

The error is from my logic. Something is wrong somewhere in my part. Not the fontrenderer

Comment: ... if you don't explain more, I don't see how you expect help.

Comment: @AxelH Posted updated with links to all the classes. What I'm sure of is that cutString is causing the stackoverflow due to recursion SOMEHOW. I'm simply unsure what's causing it, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question. If more information is required, I'll provide it once requested.

Comment: Don't use external link... first because my company use a firewall blocking does ;) but mostly because you just need to create a [mcve] with the reproduction of your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

The trace indicates that the error is in this method (simplified here);

```
String wrapFormattedStringToWidth(String str, int wrapWidth)
{
    int i = this.sizeStringToWidth(str, wrapWidth);

    if (str.length() <= i)
    {
        return str;  // exit of recursive call
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        // recursive call
        return s + "\n" + this.wrapFormattedStringToWidth(s1, wrapWidth);
    }
}
```

this method is calling itself recursively, only returning if the length of the string is less or equal to the value returned by `sizeStringToWidth`. Probably this is never happening in that particular case causing the stack overflow. Maybe a calculation error, or a strange char in the string, ...

It is hard to tell more without knowing what the methods are doing - I am unable to access gist, same problem as AxelH.